# Is it good practice to have a column for each user and a row for each user in SQL table?

Tags: sql, database

I am currently designing a "tinder" clone where I have a database of users and I want to store whether a certain user "swiped right"(liked) a different user or "swiped left"(disliked) or didn't see at all.

I want to make table that each row is a different user and each column is a different user, so if I have the value 1 stored in the row of Bob and the column of Alice I know that Bob swiped right on Alice.
So my question is, is this good practice? for n users I have to store n^2 values which seems wrong(but I guess this is unavoidable).

on top of that, there is a lot of redundent information since some people aren't sexually attracted to a certain gender so some values will never be accessed.

this is my first time using SQL so I am a bit lost right now. what would be a better way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean with "each column is a different user". I hope you don't plan to add a new column to that table each time a new user registers?

Comment: The max number of columns is limited (1024 for SqlServer), so that will also prevent this "solution", assuming a reasonable amount of users. Apart from the other issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is a bad idea.

- Adding new users requires changing the *structure8* of the table.
- You can only store one item of information but you might have more per swipe.
- The identity of the "second" user is not clear because it is embedded in the column name.

The right thing to do is to have a table with one row per swipe:

```
create table swipes (
    swipeId int primary key,   -- auto-incremented/identity/serial
    FromUserId int not null references users(user_id),
    ToUserId int not null references users(user_id),
    -- and then additional information you might want
    swipeTime timestamp,
    direction varchar(10)
);
```